# display different divs from php in different place using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am sending a form using jquery and I would like to display the html response from the php page in different places. What I mean is like I am echoing different div's and I would like to display one div on one place and the other on another.

html

```
 <div id="error"></div>
```

js

```
   success: function(response) 
        {   

    $("#error").fadeIn('slow').html(response);//this displays both divs on same place
        }
```

php

```
 if(){
    echo "<div id='alert_one'>Hi there</div>"; 
    echo "<div id='alert_two'>Something</div>";
    }
```

can I do something like

```
    success: function(response) 
        {   

         $("#div_1").fadeIn('slow').html('div_id_from_php');
       $("#div_2").fadeIn('slow').html('div_id_from_php');
        }

    <div id="div_1"></div>
    <div id="div_2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with this:

```
success: function(response)    
{   
   var $divs = $("<div>" + response + "</div>");    
   $("#div_1").fadeIn('slow').html($divs.find("#alert_one").html());
   $("#div_2").fadeIn('slow').html($divs.find("#alert_two").html());
}
```

Or like this (probably cleaner):

```
success: function(response)    
{   
   var $divs = $("<div>" + response + "</div>");    
   $("#div_1").fadeIn('slow').empty().append($divs.find("#alert_one"));
   $("#div_2").fadeIn('slow').empty().append($divs.find("#alert_two"));
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can. Just position the divs according to your need. Try to add jquery css() method for positioning. eg :

> $("#div_1").css("padding-top","20px");

for details please see: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do so this way:

on your PHP:

```
if(){
    $resp['div1']=  "<div id='alert_one'>Hi there</div>"; 
    $resp['div2']=  "<div id='alert_two'>Something</div>";
    }
echo json_encode($resp);
```

jQuery:

```
success: function(response) 
        {   
           data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
           $("#div_1").fadeIn('slow').html(data.div1);
           $("#div_2").fadeIn('slow').html(data.div2);
        }
```